# Как сделать открытие/закрытие подменю по клику не запрещая всплытие?

Tags: javascript

Имеется выпадающее подменю. Открывается по клику на второй пункт меню, закрывается по клику на него же, либо на любое пространство, кроме самого выпавшего подменю. Чтобы подменю закрывалось по клику вне его, пришлось запретить всплытие при его открытии, иначе оно открывалось и мгновенно закрывалось. Можно ли как то это реализовать не запрещая всплытие?

```js
let subMenuShow = document.querySelector('.menu li:nth-child(2)');
let subMenu = document.querySelector('.sub-menu');

// Открыть подменю
let SwitchMenu = function() {
  subMenu.classList.toggle('open');
  event.stopPropagation();
};

subMenuShow.addEventListener("click", SwitchMenu);


// Закрыть подменю
function menuClose() {
  subMenu.classList.remove('open');
}

function menuCloseClickOutside(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.sub-menu, .sub-menu *')) {
    menuClose();
  };
};

document.addEventListener('click', menuCloseClickOutside);
document.addEventListener('touchstart', menuCloseClickOutside);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно, зачем вообще хардкодить индекс элемента меню.

Можно решить задачу очень просто, и относительно гибко:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const lastChild = e.target.lastElementChild; 
    if (lastChild && lastChild.matches('.menu.sub'))
      return (e.target.classList.toggle('active'), undefined); 
    for (const mi of document.querySelectorAll('.menu > li'))
      mi.classList.remove('active'); 
  });
});
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; font-family: sans-serif; }
.menu { list-style: none; font-size: 0; padding: 0; white-space: nowrap; }
  .menu > li { position: relative; display: inline-block; padding: 0.5em; font-size: 1rem; box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #777; user-select: none; cursor: pointer; }
  .menu > li + li { margin-left: 1px; }
.menu.sub { position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; display: none; width: 100%; }
  .menu.sub > li { margin-top: 1px; }
.menu > li.active { background: #def; }
.menu > li.active > .menu.sub { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>flat</li>
  <li>with submenu
    <ul class="menu sub">
      <li>flat</li>
      <li>flat</li>
      <li>with submenu
        <ul class="menu sub">
          <li>flat</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>flat</li>
  <li>flat</li>
</ul>
```