# Как закрывать меню при нажатии в не дива на чистом js?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function f1() {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("car")[0];
    display = a.style.display;
    if (display == "none") {
      a.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      a.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="car" style="display: none;">car</div>
<button onclick="f1()">Close / Open</button>
```

Знаю что этот вопрос был много раз задан, но решение я находил только с помощью jQuery, я ещё эту библиотеку не изучал, поэтому хотелось бы узнать, как можно это решить с помощью чистого js? Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Буквально на первой странице списка вопросов с меткой [javascript]: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1035631/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function f1() {
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("car")[0];
  display = a.style.display;
  if (display == "none") {
    a.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    a.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function CloseClickOutside(e) {
    if(!e.target.matches('button')) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("car")[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
document.addEventListener('click', CloseClickOutside);
document.addEventListener('touchstart', CloseClickOutside);
```

```html
<div class="car" style="display:none">car</div>
<button onclick="f1()">Close/Open</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("car")[0];
  
function f1() {
  display = a.style.display;
  if(display == "none") {
    a.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    a.style.display = "none";
  }
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {  
  if(!event.target.closest('#menu-btn')) {
    a.style.display = "none";
  } 
});
```

```html
<div class="car" style="display: none;">car</div>
<button onclick="f1()" id="menu-btn">Close / Open</button>
```

Всё хорошо же. Потеряли `;` после `none`.

Comment: Да, я это знаю, эта функция позволяет закрывать и открывать див при нажатии на ОПРЕДЕЛЁННУЮ кнопку, а  я хотел что бы он закрывался при нажатии в НЕ дива :) Есть такое решение?)

Comment: ̶в̶ ̶Н̶Е̶   Вне дива - вы имеете ввиду, что при нажатии на любую область экрана - меню закрывалось? Верно?)

Comment: Да, всё верно..)

Comment: Ответ уже дали смотрю)